# Trac: How to change order of menu items

Tags: trac, genshi

How do I change a Trac project so the timeline is the first menu entry, *and* the default page when entering the project?

I can alter the order of entries in the project's conf file but I will still end up in the Wiki when entering.

I can disable the Wiki entry in `[mainnav]` but will still end up on the wiki page when entering.

I can't find anything in the trac documentation.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `default_handler` in the `trac.ini`.

```
[trac]
default_handler = TimelineModule
```

That should do what you want.  See the [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracIni#trac-section) for more.